# How to change the default permission name?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to change the default permission name created by django after migrating django model.

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#default-permissions) says Providing `default_permissions = []` in the class `Meta` works but

> It must be specified on the model before the model is created by
>   migrate in order to prevent any omitted permissions from being
>   created.

But is it possible to change the permission Name (codename also if possible) after the model migration also ?

```
 class ContactPage(models.Model):
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        email = models.EmailField()
        msg = models.TextField()
        sent_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.full_name

        class Meta:
            default_permissions = [] # works in the first migrate
            permissions = [
                ('can_view_contacts', 'Can View Contacts'),
                ('can_delete_contacts', 'Can Delete Contacts'),
            ]
```

Comment: Any news yet? looking for an answer to the same question...

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating an empty migration file and doing the job manually in that.